# unable to SSH but successfully pinging

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dns

I have configured a static IP in Ubuntu 20.04 i.e., `192.168.0.2`, with DNS as `192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8` and default route `192.168.0.1`. Now, as I am pinging from other machine on the same network, it is successfully pinging, but when I am trying to connect from Putty it is showing connection refused.
I have also checked my firewall for port `22` for allowing SSH connection.

This is my `ifconfig` result:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:e3:21:32:80  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp6s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f0:4d:a2:30:48:b6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3678  bytes 313364 (313.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6522  bytes 592090 (592.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 27389  bytes 2387414 (2.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 27389  bytes 2387414 (2.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx502b73e90726: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::522b:73ff:fee9:726  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:2b:73:e9:07:26  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 33137  bytes 15333492 (15.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 286  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21902  bytes 3714387 (3.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong here when I'm trying to SSH into the system using the static IP.

Comment: You haven't said if this is a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server or desktop install?  ie. do you have `openssh-server` running on it? or only a client (as is default with desktop installs; ie. you can `ssh` out, but not in)

Comment: I have ```linux-image-5.4.0-89-generic``` as kernel. Can I implement ```openssh-server``` on it?

Comment: i installed openss-server and now it is remotely connecting through SSH. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is available in server & desktop form.

The desktop product includes the ssh client by default; meaning you can `ssh` into other boxes; but not `ssh` into the machine; after all a desktop system is generally used locally.

The server product is usually used remotely; thus includes the ssh server by default, allowing you to `ssh` into the machine.

If using a desktop system, you'll likely need to

`apt install openssh-server`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `nmap` or any other tool to double check if port 22 is really open.